# remove line break that appears after a certain text from textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do I remove line breaks or empty lines that appear after a certain text in a textarea box. I tried something like this:

```
$('#mytextarea').val($('#mytextarea').val().replace('some_Text' + "\n", ''));
```

But that didn't work

Comment: What is the specific text?

Comment: Include some sample input as a few people have pointed out now.

Answer (score 0):

I found this regex **[JavaScript line breaks](http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/javascript-line-breaks.php)**

```
$('#mytextarea').val($('#mytextarea').val().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newVal = $('#mytextarea').val().replace(/some_Text[\r\n]+/, 'some_Text')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just concentrating on the regexp part of the question:

**Sample Text and Replacement Code**

```
"some texts are better than others, some_text\nsome_text\r\nsome_text\rok? some_text"
.replace(/(some_text)[\r\n]+/g, '')
```

**Result**

```
"some texts are better than others, ok? some_text"
```